# MVP и концепция событий в пользовательском интерфейсе

Tags: c#, winforms, события, архитектура, mvp

Пытаюсь разобраться с корректной работой обработки событий в пользовательском интерфейсе. Имеется следующий набор классов:

**Условное ядро приложения**

```
public class Core
{
    public string Process(string text)
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

**Presenter**

```
public class Presenter
{
    IMainForm mainForm;
    Core core;

    public Presenter(Core _core)
    {
        core = _core;
    }

    public void AssignView(IMainForm _mainForm)
    {
        mainForm = _mainForm;
        mainForm.SomethingChanged += MainForm_SomethingChanged;
    }

    private void MainForm_SomethingChanged(object sender, string e)
    {
        Process();
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        if (mainForm!=null)
        {
            mainForm.MyLabelText = core.Process(mainForm.MyTextBoxText);
        }
    }

    public void CloseView()
    {
        mainForm.SomethingChanged -= MainForm_SomethingChanged;
    }
}
```

**IMainForm**

```
public interface IMainForm
{
    Presenter Presenter { get; }
    string MyLabelText { get; set; }
    string MyTextBoxText { get; set; }
    event EventHandler<string> SomethingChanged;
}
```

**Собственно, сам код формы**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainForm
{
    public event EventHandler<string> SomethingChanged;
    public Presenter Presenter { get; private set; }
    public MainForm(Presenter presenter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Presenter = presenter;
    }

    public string MyLabelText {
        get { try { return MyLabel.Text; } catch { return default(string); } }
        set { try { MyLabel.Text = value; } catch {} }
    }

    public string MyTextBoxText {
        get { try { return MyTextBox.Text; } catch { return default(string); } }
        set { try { MyTextBox.Text = value; } catch { } }
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Presenter.Process();
    }

    private void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomethingChanged?.Invoke(this, MyTextBoxText);
    }

    private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Presenter.CloseView();
    }
}
```

**И как это все запускается. Program.cs**

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Core Core = new Core();
        Presenter MainPresenter = new Presenter(Core);
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(MainPresenter);
        MainPresenter.AssignView(mainForm);
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** Как можно более правильно вызывать события, когда что-либо изменяется в интерфейсе формы? (чтобы уведомлять об этом Presenter). Сейчас получается так, что я по событию изменения текста генерирую вызов собственного события. Мне это, естественно, не очень нравится. Как можно сделать это более правильно?

Comment: Насколько я знаю проброс события из формы в презентер - это норма mvp. Но тоже интересно услышать мнение мастеров. Единственное советую пробрасывать с помощью Invoke, дабы исключить вариант вылета в случае отсутствия подписок SomethingChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

Comment: У Вас View знает о существовании Presenter, что является неправильным, Presenter знает о модели и об интерфейсе VIew, а View не должно напрямую обращаться к Presenter.

Comment: @OleksiiPotapov А как мне тогда это более правильно сделать? Можете подсказать?

Comment: @OleksiiPotapov то есть я должен уведомлять presenter об изменениях в view через вызов событий?

Comment: Да, именно через события презентер узнает, что во view что-то произошло и реагирует на это.

Comment: @OleksiiPotapov а как можно более правильно привязать события в интерфейсе к событиям, для уведомления Presenter'a?

Comment: Так, в принципе, как Вы и делаете, в интерфейсе объявляется событие, в форме делаете проброс, а в презентере обрабатываете. По крайней мере я так делаю.

Comment: https://youtu.be/N6RNy3rPZpg вот тут неплохо объяснено.